# Calculate distance to target pixels in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, distance, image, inverse-distance-weighted

I am having a water body raster in the form "0" as water pixels values and rest of the area is "masked". I want to have my output in the form of an image such that each point in the image will represent distance from its nearest waterbody pixels.

I tried calculating eucledian distance from the water body pixels having the band name as "waterClass". No error came also the output came as masked.

Not sure what is the correct approach? The dataset used is - JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory

```
var water = ee.Image(Water_bodies.filterBounds(goalpara).sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT").first().clip(goalpara));
Map.addLayer(water,{},'water')
var dist= water.select('waterClass')
  .distance({kernel:ee.Kernel.euclidean(100), skipMasked:true})
print('dist', dist);
Map.addLayer(dist, {}, 'distance');
var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                    "bands":["distance"],
                    "max":11.180339887498949,
                    "palette":["22ff20","1a35ff","ffa925","ff0a36","2fe1ff","fd4bff"]};
Map.addLayer(dist, imageVisParam, 'distance1');
```

Here is my input-

[image]

And how I want my Output-

[image]

Comment: A related post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/300266/68792
(distance-to-water-from-every-non-water-pixel-using-google-earth-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ee.Image.distance](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-distance) method assumes that your target pixels have a non-zero value. You have stated that your target pixel value is currently zero, so you'll need to make it non-zero. Additionally, you are setting the `skipMasked` parameter to `true`, which will not provide distance-to-target calculations for masked pixels; all of your non-target pixels are masked, you need to `.unmask(0)` them or set `skipMasked` to `false`. Your code might look something like this (untested).

```js
var water = Water_bodies.filterBounds(goalpara)
  .sort("CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESMENT")
  .first()
  .clip(goalpara);
Map.addLayer(water, null, 'water')

var dist = water.select('waterClass').eq(0)
  .distance({kernel: ee.Kernel.euclidean(100), skipMasked: false})
print('dist', dist);

Map.addLayer(dist, null, 'distance');
var imageVisParam = {"opacity": 1,
                     "bands": ["distance"],
                     "max": 11.180339887498949,
                     "palette": ["22ff20","1a35ff","ffa925",
                                 "ff0a36","2fe1ff","fd4bff"]};
Map.addLayer(dist, imageVisParam, 'distance1');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to answer a question when you have to guess the used product but with 'GLCF/GLS_WATER' Image Collection it works. In this case, class water values corresponds to 2. Code looks as follows.

```
var countries =ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");
var goalpara = countries
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Goalpara'));

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('GLCF/GLS_WATER')
  .filterBounds(goalpara);

var dataset_list = dataset.toList(dataset.size());

print(dataset_list);

var water = ee.Image(ee.List(dataset_list).get(0)).select('water')
  .clip(goalpara);

water = water.updateMask(water.eq(2));

var waterVis = {
  max: 2.0,
  palette: ['blue'],
};

Map.centerObject(goalpara);
Map.addLayer(goalpara, {}, 'goalpara');
Map.addLayer(water, waterVis, 'Water');

var dist = water.select('water').eq(2)
  .distance({kernel:ee.Kernel.euclidean(100), skipMasked:false})
  .clip(goalpara)
  .rename('distance');

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                    "bands":["distance"],
                    "min":0,
                    "max":15,
                    "palette":["22ff20","1a35ff","ffa925","ff0a36","2fe1ff","fd4bff"]};

Map.addLayer(dist, imageVisParam, 'distance');
```

After running above script, I got result ('distance' layer) of following picture for **Goalpara** region in India.

[image]

Comment: The dataset used is - JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory